parse js string to python
I have a string with js code
 [{label: '&nbsp;', name: 'Confirmed', width: 30, formatter: 'checkbox'},{label: 'ID', name: 'ID', width: 100, key:true},{label: 'E-mail', name: 'F250275', width: null, formatter: clearText},{label: 'Agree', name: 'F250386', width: null, formatter: clearText},]

Is there a way to parse it to python to get list? I've tried json.loads , but get the error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 3 column 18 (char 27)
Some update, based on comments.
There isn't any options to use JS here. That's why I didn't put JS tag here

So you need to validate your json (jsonlint.com).You probably need to use JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJ). To get your JS object as valid json before you can use it in pyton.

@scrappedcola - I get this string already in python, and can't make any js operations

"I've tried json.loads , but get errors" - What specifically did you try and what specifically was the error?  Please include a [mcve] in the question.  (Though at the very least it's worth noting that your JSON isn't valid.)

It's not valid json or python. Parsing will be more involved. Go back to the source and fix it, if you can.

@David - done, thanks

@Headmaster: The error message is telling you that you don't have valid JSON.  If you can, correct the data to be valid JSON.  Otherwise what you have is a custom data structure which resembles JSON but isn't.  You could write your own parsing logic for that.  Or, thinking outside the box, you might write a JavaScript utility to eval this as code into a variable and serialize it out to JSON, and consume that utility from your Python code.

The thing about the JSON methods in Python is, it expects your string to be valid JSON... Just because the J and the S in JSON stand for Javascript, that doens't mean all Javascript objects are valid JSON.

@Headmaster: If even invoking a command-line JavaScript application isn't an option, while I've never tried this it may be at least worth investigating... You may be able to construct an HTML page in memory (create a template of some kind where your code just plugs in this string value where appropriate) which takes this data structure in JavaScript code, serializes it to JSON, and outputs that JSON to the page.  Then see if you can load that page into Selenium in-memory so it executes the code, and use Selenium to observe the result on that "page".

To use eval in js, you would have to handle the last item: formatter: clearText. What's clearText? How will that convert?

@001 - there is no option to use js

@Headmaster: If there's some artificial requirement that absolutely no JavaScript code can be used in any form at all (except obviously for the otherwise incomplete JavaScript code used in the string itself) then what you have is simply a custom data format.  You'd need to write custom logic to parse that data format.  Maybe you define some tokenization logic, maybe you use regular expressions to fetch the specific values you want, etc.  But "how to parse it to Python" becomes too broad without first making some attempt to parse your custom data format.

Here is the package for such things https://pypi.org/project/calmjs.parse/
Some example
from calmjs.parse.unparsers.extractor import ast_to_dict
from calmjs.parse import es5

my_string_with_js = "here is js code from the question"
configuration = es5(my_string_with_js)
baseconf = ast_to_dict(configuration)


If it's this same general format, you can attempt to convert it to valid JSON by quoting the property names and converting the single quotes to double quotes.
Here's some demo code:
import re
import json

def js2json(str):
    l = [];
    objs = re.findall(r"({[^}]*})", str); # get objects
    for obj in objs: 
        obj = re.sub(r"([{,]\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)", r'\1"\2"', obj); # quote object property names
        obj = re.sub(r"(:\s*)'?([^',\}]+)'?", r'\1"\2"', obj); # quote object property values
        l.append(json.loads(obj)) 
    return l

str="[{label: '&nbsp;', name: 'Confirmed', width: 30, formatter: 'checkbox'},{label: 'ID', name: 'ID', width: 100, key:true},{label: 'E-mail', name: 'F250275', width: null, formatter: clearText},{label: 'Agree', name: 'F250386', width: null, formatter: clearText},]"

print(js2json(str))

